# Placing Excel Data in ArcMap/ArcScene similar to Image Georeferencing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, latitude-longitude, geolocation, missing-data

I have XYZ-dataset of Temperature Data in Excel, with no `(Lat, Lon)` added.

Every time when I try to display the Data in ArcScene the Programm tells me, that a Spacial Reference is missing (of course). That means I am unable to visualize the dataset in the right environment.

Is there anyway, especially in ArcScene to place the dataset in the same way in which it is done with Georeference Images?

Long story short, is it possible to Georeference a Layer, that do not contain `(Lat, Lon)`-Datapoints?

Edit: The Rasta is located in Zürich (Swiss). You are right, my Excel Data is in XYZ Data. It is a four coloum set (X-Coordinate, Y-Coordinate, Z-Coordinate and Temperature Value)[image]

Comment: When you say you have XYZ-dataset, do you mean you have XYZ coordinates in your Excel file? If so, can you post a sample point so we can take a look at the values? Also, where is your data supposed to be located approximately? (country/state/province)?

Comment: The Rasta is located in Zürich (Swiss). You are right, my Excel Data is in XYZ Data. It is a four coloum set (X-Coordinate, Y-Coordinate, Z-Coordinate and Temperature Value)

Comment: Are your X and Y values all zeroes? In any case, you will need a reference if you want to georeference that. Either a reference layer, or point, etc. expressed in an known coordinate system. Do you have any metadata with your file? Did you ask your data provider what reference he used and how the data is structured?

Comment: No, not all of them. Its a Rasta (248x248). I now exactly where the Rasta is located, as i got the georefed. Buildings as a Layer, but the simultated Temperature Values came via textfile without any geografical Reference.

Comment: Maybe you could try the Raster To Points tool, it can generate a point layer from your georeferenced raster, then you can join your excel data to it and recreate a new raster with Points to Raster.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options:

- Join table records based on common id to an existing feature/layer.
- Manually create a point layer and digitize in the point locations and assign each feature an id common with the table record.  Then join table to point layer.

Tables can be adding into the software as a standalone table, however the records cannot be symbolized on a map without xy values.